# ReactJS - Router gives blank page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

Hello i am a Beginner in react programming.
what i want to do in my front page is multiple redirects using Router.
But i don't know what i'm doing wrong!

could you help?

the app must have a nested menu on the left that redirect to the correct page.
plus in the front page product should redirect on the product.js page!

On the left on the treenav menu i will have a products that redirect on the product page and the on the front page i will have the submenu products inside a BrowserHomeCategory that once clicked redirects to the products.js page

i will show you how the app is structured.

This is my AppJS:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import {MDBSideNav, MDBSideNavMenu, MDBBtn, MDBIcon} from 'mdb-react-ui-kit';
import BasicCollctionADImage from '../images/ads/basic_collectionAD.png';
import replicalogo from "../images/replica_logo.svg";
import '../styles/css/browserstyle.css';
import TreeNavigation from "../core/treenav/treenav_container";
import BrowserHeader from "../core/browser/browser_stickyheader";
import CollectionAD from "../core/browser/collectionad";
import BrowserHomeCategory from "../core/browser/browser_home_category";
import useCustomTitle from "../core/hooks/pagetitlehook";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import Products from "./products"


export default function ReplicaBrowser(props) {
    const [slimOpen, setSlimOpen] = useState(true);
    const sidenavContent = useRef(null);
    const [container, setContainer] = useState(null);
    const [mode, setMode] = useState('side');
    useEffect(() => {
        setContainer(sidenavContent.current);
    }, []);

    useCustomTitle(props);



    return (
        <>
            <MDBSideNav isOpen={slimOpen} slim={false} mode={mode} contentRef={container} closeOnEsc={false} slimCollapsed={true} backdrop={false}
                getOpenState={(e: any) => setSlimOpen(e)}>
                <MDBSideNavMenu>
                    <img src={replicalogo} className="logo" alt="R3plica Logo"/>
                    <TreeNavigation/>
                </MDBSideNavMenu>
            </MDBSideNav>
            
            
            <div ref={sidenavContent} className="BrowserContent">
                <BrowserHeader/>
                <DebugArea/>
                <CollectionAD image={BasicCollctionADImage}/>
                <br/>
                <BrowserHomeCategory title="Products" data="/products/getrecent" href="/products" />
                <br/>
                <BrowserHomeCategory title="Materials" data="/materials/getrecent" href="/materials" />
                <br/>
                <BrowserHomeCategory title="Brands" data="/brands/getrecent" href="/brands" />
             
            </div>
            <Router>
                <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/products">Products</Link>
                </li>
                </ul>
             
                    <Routes>
                        <Route exact path='/products' element={< Products />}></Route>
                    </Routes>
                    </Router>
            
        </>
    );
```

this is my productsJS:

```
import React from 'react';

function Products (){
return <address>
            You can find us here:<br />
            GeeksforGeeks<br />
            5th & 6th Floor, Royal Kapsons, A- 118, <br />
            Sector- 136, Noida, Uttar Pradesh (201305)
        </address>
}

export default Products;
```

this is my treenav-item:

```
export default function TreeNavItem(props)
{
    return(
        <details className="tree-nav__item is-expandable">
            {(props.active) ? <div className="active"></div> : null}
            <summary className="tree-nav__item-title">{props.title}</summary>
            <div className="tree-nav__item">
                {props.children}
            </div>
        </details>
    )
}
```

treenavmain:

```
export default function TreeNavMain(props)
{
  return( <details className=" is-expandable" open>
  <summary><img className="home-logo" src={props.icon} /><div className="hometitle">{props.title}</div></summary>
  {props.children}
</details>)
}
```

treenav-container:

```
import '../../styles/css/treenav.css'
import HomeIcon from '../../images/icon_home.svg';
import TreeNavItem from "./treenav_item";
import TreeNavMain from "./treenav-main";
export default function TreeNavigation(props)
{
    return (
        <nav className="tree-nav">
            <TreeNavMain title="Home" icon={HomeIcon}>
                <TreeNavItem title="Products" active>
                    <TreeNavItem title="Materials" active></TreeNavItem>
                    <TreeNavItem title="Materials">
                        <TreeNavItem title="Brands"></TreeNavItem>
                    </TreeNavItem>
                    <TreeNavItem title="Materials">
                        <TreeNavItem title="Brands"></TreeNavItem>
                    </TreeNavItem>
                </TreeNavItem>

                <TreeNavItem title="Brands"></TreeNavItem>

            </TreeNavMain>
        </nav>
    );
}
```

browserhome category:

```
import {MDBContainer, MDBCol, MDBRow, MDBBtn, MDBIcon} from "mdb-react-ui-kit";
import IconFollowPage from '../../images/icon_followpage.svg';
export default function BrowserHomeCategory(props)
{
    return(
        <div className="browserCategoryContainer">
            <div className="browserCategoryHeading">
                <MDBContainer fluid>
                    <MDBRow>
                        <MDBCol size="2">
                            <a href={props.href}>
                                <h1>{props.title} <img src={IconFollowPage}/></h1>
                            </a>
                        </MDBCol>
                        <MDBCol size="9"/>
                        <MDBCol size="1">
                            <MDBBtn floating color="light" outline>
                                <MDBIcon fas icon="chevron-left" color="dark"/>
                            </MDBBtn>
                            <MDBBtn floating color="light" outline>
                                <MDBIcon fas icon="chevron-right" color="dark" />
                            </MDBBtn>
                        </MDBCol>
                    </MDBRow>
                </MDBContainer>
            </div>
            <div className="browserCategoryItems">
                Items
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I don't see any issues here that would cause a blank page to be displayed/rendered. What exactly is the issue? If you navigate to `"/products"` what is rendered? Are there any errors? Please [edit] to include more details on the issue.

Comment: hello @DrewReese! i've put the content of product js in the question. it just gives me not found

Comment: Ok, and when you navigate to `"/products"` does *that* content render to the DOM? *What* gives you "not found"?

Comment: `<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"><div class="Toastify"></div>Not found!</div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  

</body>`

Comment: it gave me the default page i think

Comment: So is the issue that you are seeing this "Not Found!" text under all the regular app content? I'm also guessing that you are seeing the `"/"` route/path by default, but you are missing rendering anything on that path, so OFC there's a "blank page" on `"/"`. I'm certain if you navigated to `"/products"` I'm sure you'd see that content rendered.

Comment: no i see the regular app content is the `"/products"` that i don't see. when i click on products it gave me not found

Comment: You don't see anything at all if you navigate to `"/products"`? Can you clarify what "click on products" means exactly? The `<Link to="/products">Products</Link>`? If so I see no reason for the link to the route not to work and I see no reason for `Products` not to render.

Comment: i'm sorry drew i'll try to be more specific exacly what your assuming i click the `<Link to="/products">Products</Link>` and in the `"/products"` it show me not found

Comment: No worries. Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this routing/rendering issue that we could inspect live? Perhaps there's an issue elsewhere causing a problem.

Comment: here you go i deleted the link stuff i made upther https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-bhaskara-u7cn5e?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks for the sandbox, but unfortunately it appears to be incomplete. Were there perhaps some files/changes that didn't get saved?

Comment: ehy @DrewReese you were right check again i've managed to save! thank you very much!!

Comment: Is there a new sandbox link to use? The one from your previous comment still has empty files.

Comment: hi drew thanks for not giving up on me 
i will try it later today it doesnt seem to work i will keep you posted!

Comment: @DrewReese i've done it! https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-ardinghelli-bioymw
i understood how to save!

Comment: You've some significant issues in your `src/core/browser` code. The router is working and rendering the `ReplicaBrowser` once `ApiWrapper.isAuthenticated()` returns a truthy value. IMHO this isn't a `react-router-dom` issue at all. Check your replica browser component code. I think there's an issue with the `mdb-react-ui-kit` library you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using React Router the default page displayed is '/', in order to reach your products page you need to navigate to '/products'.

For example, when you first start your react app locally it's hosted on localhost:3000, if you then navigate to localhost:3000/products you should see your products page